# Split HTML string into sections based on specific tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string representing a HTML snippet like this:

```
const bookString = "<h1>Chapter 1: The Beginning</h1>
<p>It was a dark and stormy night...</p>
<p>Tom ran up the stairs...</p>
<p>A shot rang out!</p>

<h1>Chapter 2: A Day at the Zoo</h1>
<p>The door swung open...</p>"
```

You get the idea, it's a book where I only expect to see h1, p, em/strong/i/b tags.  (This comes from the library Mammoth which takes a Word document and gives me a HTML string.) I want to write some JS that splits it up based on chapter, like so:

```
const chapters = [
  {
    title: "The Beginning",
    content: 
      "<p>It was a dark and stormy night...</p>
      <p>Tom ran up the stairs...</p>
      <p>A shot rang out!</p>"
    ]
  }
];
```

Then I can pass that to an ebook-generating library.

Should I use a HTML parsing library like Cheerio to do this? I can't quite figure out selections, like "for each `h1`, save a title, then for each `p` following that `h1`,  push to array..." Or should I use regexes, despite the common advice to never use regexes on HTML?

Comment: Can you post a cheerio [mcve] that almost does what you want?

Comment: Where are you wanting to do this....server or client side? If do it client side can use dom as parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Cheerio, you can use the [`nextUntil()`](https://cheerio.js.org/?#nextuntilselector-filter) method to get all elements up to one identified by a passed selector

```
//get all elements until the next h1 is encountered
$('h1').nextUntil('h1')
```

Using that you can then just `map()` over the h1 collection getting each set of contents and finally create your object

```
const chapters = $('h1').map((index,h1)=>{
  let content = $(h1).nextUntil('h1').map((index,p)=>$.html(p)).get().join('');
  return {
    title:$(h1).html(),
    content:content
  };
}).get();
```

[repl.it Demo](https://repl.it/@PatrickEvans/SO-51114918)

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use a series of `split`s to sort the string and break it into parts, and then do some cleanup and build a new Array by mapping the initial "broken" string and internally split again to get the (clean) title & content

```js
var bookString = `<h1>Chapter 1: The Beginning</h1>
<p>It was a dark and stormy night...</p>
<p>Tom ran up the stairs...</p>
<p>A shot rang out!</p>

<h1>Chapter 2: A Day at the Zoo</h1>
<p>The door swung open...</p>`;


var chapters = bookString.split('<h1>').filter(n => n).map(text => {
  var cut = text.replace(/\n/g, '').split(': ')[1].split('</h1>');
  return {
    title   : cut[0],
    content : cut[1]
  }
});

console.log(chapters);
```

Comment: Could also just trim() `text` if it's fine for the results to have newlines in the body.

Comment: @SamVK - you cannot trim because new lines are not necessarily at the edges of the string. For example, `cut[1]` might have numerous `\n` spread anywhere within the string